# Регулярка и её шаблоны

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Возник вопрос как сделать регулярного выражения, которое должно сканировать следующие шаблон текста: "1:b088d86f-556e-4a94-8e75-702851135ac5", то бишь {Id}:{Guid}?

Comment: Не совсем понял, что имеете ввиду под "сканированием". Но если хотите найти все строки подходящие по формату, то:
`^\d+:.+$` ^$ - начало, конец строки. \d - число .+ - любые символы, в неограниченном кол-ве

Comment: @raspberry, у меня есть строка и её надо проверить на коректность данных, важно что ID был положительным и как-то проверить, что формат Guid был введен верно

Comment: Может тогда так? `^\d+:\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+$`. id будет пропущен, если содержит только цифры, следовательно, если будет "-123", с минусом, как спецсимволом, не прокатит. А \w - алфавитно-цифровой или '_' символ, тогда если ваш guid всегда содержит данные именно в этом формате, с разделителем в виде "-", то это должно работать

Comment: @raspberry, да, спасибо работает как надо!

Comment: Вряд ли `^\d+:\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+$` [работает как надо](https://regex101.com/r/6dzkbq/2).

Comment: @Wiktor, в моём случае он подходит

Comment: @Yarik08 Это до поры до времени.